# Is there a way to make cmyk thumbnail, images, look good in ubuntu

Tags: color-management, cmyk

Is there a way to make CMYK thumbnails, images, look good in Ubuntu. Some applications like Krita and Scribus show correct colour on screen. I know they support CMYK profiles. But I wanted to know that if ubuntu can be tweaked to show correct(the nearest possible) colours. I also know CMYK is shown as RGB on screen, and it cannot match the print output.

Other than the above mentioned applications, CMYK colours are over saturated everywhere on the system even in the thumbnails. I know we have to colour correct the monitor with hardware products like Colorhug etc.

Please tell me if there is a program or tweak that can be done in the colour manager to correct this problem.

Comment: I don't know if i mentioned enough information about this question. No one has answered yet.